# How to provide the key value in a join when a match is not found

Tags: join, db2

My DB2 database has the following tables:

**CustomerLog**

```
customer  version  userid  description
--------  -------  ------  ----------------------------
Orange    101      2       New customer
Orange    102      2       Bespoke widgets added
Orange    103      4       Fix errors after review
Orange    104      3       Priority bugfix
Peach     101      1       New customer
Peach     102      3       Custom screens for Peach
...
```

**Users**

```
userid  name
------  -------------------
1       Andrew
2       Belinda
3       Charles
```

With the select statement:

```
select c.customer, c.version, u.name, c.description
from customerlog c, users u
where c.customer='Orange'
and c.userid = u.userid
```

I get the following result:

```
customer  version  name        description
--------  -------  ----------  ----------------------------
Orange    101      Belinda     New customer
Orange    102      Belinda     Bespoke widgets added
Orange    104      Charles     Priority bugfix
```

If I instead used a left join, I could get the following row selected as well:

```
Orange    103      null        Fix errors after review
```

... but is there a way to get the userid in place of the null?  ie:

```
Orange    103      4           Fix errors after review
```

Comment: Perhaps there's an easy fix, if you would like to update your question with your left join query.

Answer (score 3):

Use [COALESCE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm#SQLRF00617)

> Purpose
>
> COALESCE returns the first non-null expr in the expression list. You must specify at least two expressions. If all occurrences of expr evaluate to null, then the function returns null.

```
select c.customer, c.version, coalesce(u.name, to_char(c.userid)) as user c.description
from customerlog c
     left join users u on u.userid = c.userid
where c.customer='Orange'
```

Comment: Assuming user ID is numeric, should probably add a char() or varchar() so that the types match.   Though the DB will likely implicitly convert it.